# Split content of a cell if it has more than one string

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, iteration, cell

I am kinda confuse with my problem.

I am working with a cell array,generally, I have a set of words in which scattered in different cells and I want to split the cell that contains more than one string into different cell so at the end I will have have cells that only contain one single string

Example

```
{data}.

    {1X2} 

    {1X1}
```

The data used is organized as follow

```
data 
 book
  => story, computer
    => politic



 I use x= regexp (data, '=>', 'split')
```

I wonder how can I split the cells that contain more than one string

```
j= regexp (x, ',', 'split');
```

it results in

```
{1x2 cell}    {1x1 cell}
```

the variable j has

```
<1x2 cell>  ' politic'
```

so, how can I split the content in cell 1 into two cells so that it should be like

```
'story' 'computer' 'politic'
```

or alternatively,

```
row 1  :'story' 'computer' 
row 2  : 'politic'
row [n]: 'whatever' 'so'
```

The cells that show no specific string appear to have more than one string, I want precisely break that cell's content to different cells
Can someone help me please,

Moreover, if it is possible and I can make each cell, even if it contain one single string, in a row.

I highly appreciate your time and splendid knowledge

Comment: How can we know what's inside your example? Post the full content of your example. Your `regexp()` should be correct, unless words are separated by blanks as well.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Yes there is a whitespace and newlines

Answer (score 0):

```
data{1} = 'fool';
data{2} = 'freedom, tyranny';
for ix = 1 : numel(data); 
      j = regexp(data{ix}, ',', 'split'); 
      if numel(j) > 1; 
          data{ix} = j; 
      end; 
end
```

Do the above, and if you examine data on the command line you get:

```
data = 
  'fool'    {1x2 cell}
```